# windows phone ndef record for skype

Tags: nfc, windows-phone-8, skype, ndef

I want to create i NFC tag for r skype call by my phone doesn't recognise it  (nokia lumia 920). This is how my ndef record looks like when is read by phone. Is there something wrong with it?

```
 Sp sub-record No.1
 MB:1; ME:0; CF:0; SR:1; IL:0;
 Type: wkt:U
 Uri: skype:dd?call
 Sp sub-record No.2
 MB:0; ME:0; CF:0; SR:1; IL:0;
 Type: wkt:T
 Language: en
 Encoding: UTF-8
 Text: dd
 Sp sub-record No.3
 MB:0; ME:1; CF:0; SR:1; IL:0;
 Type: wkt:act
 Payload:
```

P.S. if it is read by android device for example is it gonna work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the same test and indeed the Windows Phone doesn't recognize the tag. Having a well-known type URI with the 'skype:dd?call' part also results in a message stating there is no app on the phone. After a search in the Store, now app could be find by the store itself.

A normal SmartPoster record is detected without any problem, same goes for other well-known type URI records.

Tested the same tag on a Android device (4.1.2) and the tag application pops up. In the tag application, I can select Skype which starts Skype to make the call.

**Update:**
Just tested the URI via a webpage with the code supplied by Skype on http://developer.skype.com/skype-uri But this has the same result, no app found on the phone nor an application found in the Store.

Your Ndef-message is correct.